Idiomatic approach to query hierarchical of heterogeneous data
Edit:
Maybe my problem is much more simple than I initially thought. My problem is in fact how to query complex objects (with nested objects) in relational databases. Maybe I just need to query each container level separately and do some treatment in go code to re-assemble the structure tree programmatically… My initial thought was to do the job directly in a big query for performance and simplicity but maybe relational DBs are not the best tool for what I’m trying to accomplish here. Or maybe using json or even an ORM abstraction is the only alternative to this situation. I should have a look at popular go ORMs code to see how they query such table structure to see how they do it.
Original Question:
I'm working on a personal project implying to represent hierarchical data with permission management on each node level (inheritance allowed) which I'll call containers here for simplicity. Like a structure of folder and files in standard file system. I am working on a stack which is PostgreSQL on one side and go(lang) as backend language. I'm a complete beginner with PostgreSQL so don't hesitate to tell me if my design is completely wrong...
My problem comes from querying this kind of structure in PGSQL since each container has common columns but has also specific columns. So there is the idea of inheritance and recursivity but also polymorphism since each level is a container with common columns. One point to note is that since I'm using separate tables for each container, my structure is static and there will be no infinite sublevels.
Here is a simplified diagram:

Each container on this diagram has a dedicated join table with a permission table to handle permission by container level. But I don't think this is relevant here.
In the project I'm building I'm trying to query this structure all at once by representing the tree as objects containing sub objects just like json would do it. I currently succeed to query and get the results I want by using a combination of json_object and json_agg functions in one query but since I'm using golang I would like to use standard SQL or PL/SQL query to return result in native types and avoid a json marshalling. The idea would be to have a struct for each container type with the corresponding fields and for each container level (here A and B) having an array or slice containing the children containers.
Due to this problem, I started to question my structure and I imagined having only one table container with a JSON column for all the specific data values inside of it but it would implies treatment in golang to dispatch the children structs in each corresponding parent struct since the result of the query would be at the same level...
I think this kind of situations is pretty common but I don't find any ressources on it... So I'm wondering how the others are getting their programming objects filled up with this kind of structure ?
Maybe PostgreSQL is not the right tool, but for the rest of my project I need to have a relationnal structure of my data and I would avoid mixing multiple technologies to avoid complexity...
So please if you have any idea... or maybe critics about the model don't hesitate to comment. Thank you so much.

You could try extracting the common columns into a separate table as you could then use a recursive query to obtain the hierarchical bit.
Something like:
CREATE TABLE dt_containiers (
    id serial,
    parent_id integer,
    name taxt,
    ...
    CONSTRAINT dt_containiers_pk PRIMARY KEY ( id ),
    CONSTRAINT dt_containiers_fk01 FOREIGN KEY ( parent_id ) REFERENCES dt_containiers ( id )
    ) ;

which you could then query using something like:
WITH RECURSIVE toc AS (
    SELECT base.id,
            '{}'::integer[] AS parents,
            base.parent_id,
            0 AS tree_depth,
            ARRAY [ dense_rank () OVER (
                ORDER BY base.name ) ] AS outln,
            ARRAY[base.id] AS id_path,
            ARRAY[base.name] AS name_path
        FROM dt_containiers base
        WHERE base.parent_id IS NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT base.id,
            q.parents || base.parent_id,
            base.parent_id,
            ( q.tree_depth + 1 ) AS tree_depth,
            ( q.outln || dense_rank () OVER (
                PARTITION BY base.parent_id
                ORDER BY base.name ) ) AS outln,
            q.id_path || base.id,
            q.name_path || base.name
        FROM dt_containiers base
        JOIN toc q
            ON ( base.parent_id = q.id
                AND NOT base.id = ANY ( q.parents ) ) -- avoid cyclic references
)
SELECT toc.id,
        toc.parent_id,
        --toc.parents,
        toc.id_path[1] AS top_parent_id,
        toc.id_path,
        toc.tree_depth,
        pg_catalog.array_to_string ( toc.outln, '.'::text ) AS outln,
        pg_catalog.array_to_string ( toc.name_path, ': '::text ) AS name_path
    FROM toc
    ...
 ;


Thanks for your answer. Extracting the common columns in a dedicated table is getting me back to a standard recursive/CTE query where I cannot have access to the specific data for each container. Maybe my problem is much more basic that I thought and is just a matter of how to query complex objects in relational databases…
